# 'Unable to verify your data submission' error on Yii2, but only on several cases

Tags: php, yii2, csrf

I'm using Yii version 2.0.6, advanced template. I got several notification from the log that someone using my app has got 'Unable to verify your data submission'. The problem is, I myself can't reproduce the problem, and the problem only occur several times, while most of the users don't get this problem. Here are some logs for the problem :

- http://pastebin.com/98BN9jkS
- http://pastebin.com/h1CcgdEu
- http://pastebin.com/qSQa4RrE
- http://pastebin.com/Zhp0jmNX

I am using adcanced template with backend and frontend in the same domain. Here are my config file :

- [Backend config](http://pastebin.com/gpXJ5qAV)
- [Frontend config](http://pastebin.com/ZHgdr5P4)

I also already using `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` in my layout. This the `<head>` section of my layout : http://pastebin.com/4N6z84aN

What might be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: show your layouts (main.php) `<head>` section please

Comment: This is the head section : http://pastebin.com/4N6z84aN

Comment: Open login page. Do not login or do anything in other tab. Wait 30 minutes. Now click login. See what happens.

Comment: Can it be that your `frontendCSRF` cookie expires?

Comment: I try several times, fill a form, and then wait 30 minutes without doing anything, and then submit the form. It doesn't show any problem.

Comment: In your request you need a cookie validation key; This may not solve your exact problem, but you still need one for csrf validation to work properly

Comment: cookie validation key is generated by default in main-local.php. I'm still can't get rid of this problem :(